# If $f$ is continuous and injective on an interval, then it is strictly monotonic- what's wrong with this proof?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I've tried proving the following theorem:

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is continuous and injective, then it is also strictly monotonic.

This is my attempt at a proof:

Since $f$ is injective and $a\neq b$, $f(a)\neq f(b)$; then, either $f(b)>f(a)$ or viceversa. Supposing that the former holds, $f(b)$ is the maximum value of the function and $f(a)$ is the minimum. In fact, let $a<z<b$ be a real number such that $f(z)$ is the maximum and consider the restriction $f_1$ of $f$ to $[a,z]$. Then, since $f(a)<f(b)<f(z)$, and $f$ is continuous, by the intermediate value theorem, there is $a<y<c$ such that $f(b)=f_1(y)=f(y)$; but, since $y<b$, this contradicts the hypothesis of injectivity.

An analogous proof shows that $f(a)$ is the minimum.

Now, let $a<x<b$ and consider the restriction $f_2$ of $f$ to $[x,b]$; $f_2$ is still an injective and continuous function, therefore $f_2(x)=f(x)$ is the minimum of $f_2$; that is, for any $y>x$, $f(x)\leq f(y)$. The equality case, though, never holds since $f$ is injective. Hence $f$ is strictly increasing.

If $f(a)>f(b)$ the proof is the same and the function is strictly decreasing.

I can't find the mistake in this proof but I think there is one, since my textbook provides one that is far longer and more difficult. Can you help me find it? (If it is correct, by the way, could you provide some feedback on how it is written?)

Comment: Looks fine to me (the key technical input is indeed the intermediate value theorem). What does your book do?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan the author starts like I did, supposing that $f(a)<f(b)$. Then he takes two points $c<d$ on the interval, and then proves that $f(d)\leq f(c)$ can't be the case. He defines two continuous functions, $x(t)=a+t(c-a)$ and $y=b+t(d-b)$. with $t\in [0,1]$. Then he observes that $f(x(0))=f(a)<f(b)=f(y(0))$ and $f(y(1))=f(d)\leq f(c)=f(x(1))$ and introduces the function $F(t)=f(y(t))-f(x(t))$. He then says that $F$ is continuous and it is easy to verify that $F(1)\leq 0<F(1)$. By the intermediate value theorem there is $0<t<1$ for which $F(t)=0$, that is $f(x(t))=f(y(t))$.

Comment: Finally, since $f$ is injective, $x(t)=y(t)$, that is $t(d-c)+(1-t)(b-a)=0$. Since $b>a$ and $d>c$ this is absurd. Hence $f(c)<f(d)$.

Comment: I don't think I would call this "far longer and more difficult," but I agree that it's more work than necessary.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan You are probably right, it's just me freaking out when I see a proof that *looks* quite long and difficult!

Comment: In your first paragraph, I think you are using z and c to represent the same number, but otherwise this looks good to me, too.