# If a function is continuous and one to one and is defined on a connected subset of R, is it monotonic that connected subset?

Tags: real-analysis

I read the proof for an interval here: 
[If a function is continuous and one-to-one then it's strictly monotonic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668257/if-a-function-is-continuous-and-one-to-one-then-its-strictly-monotonic)

I understand the proof but am not sure if it applies also to connected subsets on R?

Comment: Indeed, and the proof is almost the same. Try to prove it yourself :)

Comment: The connected subsets on $\mathbb R$ are exactly the intervals.