# Find all functions $f\colon\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ that satisfy $|f(x)-f(y)| =3|x-y|$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

> **Problem:** Find all functions $f\colon\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ that satisfy $|f(x)-f(y)| =3|x-y|$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

**My Solution:** Take two cases.

*Case 1:* Assume that $f(x)-f(y)=3(x-y)$. Then $f(x)-3x=f(y)-3y$ and therefore $f(x)=3x+c$.

*Case 2:* Assume that $f(x)-f(y)=3(y-x)$. Then $f(x)+3x=f(y)+3y$ and therefore $f(x)=-3x+c$.

Is there any problem with my solution?I want to mean is it necessary to state that f is continuous , one-one ,monotone? What is wrong with my argument?

Comment: If I take the whole modulus sign in LHS then we have to consider only 2 cases . Right?

Comment: A priori, you cannot exclude that different $x,y$ lead to different cases, so you need some additional argument.

Comment: you should divide the equation by $\vert x-y\vert$ this will give you that the function is differentiable and its derivative is $\pm 3$.

Comment: @Nathanael Skrepek But it is not necessary that the function is differentiable.

Comment: There is a priori no reason that a function which satisfies $f(x)-f(y)=3|x-y|$ satisfies one of $f(x)-f(y)=3(x-y)$ and $f(x)-f(y)=3(y-x)$. A single function could, conceivably, satisfy one of the equations some times, and the other equation some times.

Comment: it is by what i have written.

Comment: @Arthur So what should be the other conditions?

Comment: The right answer is the one on the duplicate with the most votes (not the accepted answer): since continuous, injective functions are [strictly monotone](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1668257/534616) (prove this), case analysis turns out to be valid.